# how to prove this proposition

Tags: real-analysis

Let $T \in L^k(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$ and define $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ via $f(x) = T(x^{\otimes k})$.  Then $f \in C^k(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R}^m)$, and 
\begin{equation}
 D^k f(x)(y^{(1)},\dotsc,y^{(k)}) = \sum_{P \in S_k} T(y^{(P(1))},\dotsc, y^{(P(k))})
\end{equation}
for every choice of $y^{(j)} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $j=1,\dotsc,k$.  In particular, this means that $D^k f(x) = k! \mathcal{S}T$, where $\mathcal{S}T$ is the symmetrization of $T$.  Moreover, $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R}^m)$ and $D^j f =0$ for $j \ge k+1$.

This is left as an exercise in my lecture note... but I don't know how to proceed this. The hint is by induction.